# Unable to open Windows Mobile 5.0 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-5.0

In our team we use Visual Studio 2010 for development and we've inherited a Visual Studio 2008 mobile project which requires the following

- Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK.msi
- Windows Mobile 5.0 Smartphone
  SDK.msi

We do have a laptop running Windows Vista and has Visual Studio 2008 installed. Whenever we try to install the above SDKs we are getting the following error message

> Software development tools required to use this SDK for application
>   development are not installed on this workstation. Before trying to
>   run the Setup Wizard again, verify that the required software is
>   installed. To determine which software development tools are required,
>   see the Microsoft Web site at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=21615&clcid=0x409, which you
>   can open in an external browser window by clicking the Open Browser
>   button.

Unfortunately, the link just redirects to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/

Searching for Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK requirements brings up

- Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1, Windows XP
- Visual Studio 2005 Standard, Professional, and Team Suite Editions
- Active Sync 4.0 Developer Preview (build 4343)

Is there anything we can do to open this project?

Comment: Did you downloaded the WM5 SDK recently or used a already, possibly outdated, installer? Maybe running the install as Administrator will help (right click and select "run as admin"). Windows XP did not have this security option.

Comment: I've downloaded WM5 SDK recently from Microsoft's website. When right clicking the install file, there is no option for "run as administrator". Not sure what else to check.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows Vista, then you actually need Windows Mobile Device Center, not ActiveSync. There are two versions of WMDC one for [x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3182) and [x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14) processors. Be sure to get the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The project is on hold at the moment, so will try if the situation changes.